# Как изменить скорость в http ONVIF запросе к Pelco камере?

Tags: c++, qt, http, onvif

Я успешно отправляю GET http запросы к Pelco камере, но не могу изменить скорость поворота камеры в команде центрирования камеры по точке.

```
//Отправляем POST Запрос по http на PELCO камеру
static QNetworkAccessManager manager;

//Подготавливаем URL
QUrl url("http://"+ipCamera.toString()+"/onvif/ptz_service");

//Подготавливаем Заголовок
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "text/xml");
request.setRawHeader("action", "http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl#RelativeMove");
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + QByteArray(QString("admin:1234567890").toUtf8()).toBase64());

//Подготавливаем запрос
QString body = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
               " xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl\" "
               "xmlns:sch=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema\"><s:Bo"
               "dy><ns1:RelativeMove><ns1:ProfileToken>0</ns1:ProfileToken><ns1:Translation><sch:PanTilt "
               "x=\"%1\" y=\"%2\" space=\"ur"
               "n:schemas-pelco-com:onvif:ptz/PanTiltSpaces/PercentFOVSpace\"></sch:PanTilt><sch:Zoom x=\"100\" spa"
               "ce=\"urn:schemas-pelco-com:onvif:ptz/ZoomSpaces/PercentFOVSpace\"></sch:Zoom></ns1:Translat"
               "ion><ns1:Speed><sch:PanTilt x=\"0.01\" y=\"0.01\"/>"
               "<sch:Zoom x=\"1\"/>"
               "</ns1:Speed></ns1:RelativeMove></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
```

Тут раздел speed Не исправен, можете подсказать, как написать правильно?

Comment: ¿Что значит *"не исправен"*?

Comment: не исправен, значит не правильный